# iOS Custom Keyboard : compute predictions outside extension

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, keyboard

I am currently working on a C# iOS custom keyboard and I'm stuck with random crashes on an iPad that I was given (it works well on other pads). My extension (keyboard) loads a 50000 lines CSV into some lists as a dictionary and do predictions computations from it. At some point, when the user is typing, the keyboard crashes, even if I'm under the 30 Mb memory limit (according to GC.GetTotalMemory, I'm often at 12 Mb). So I thought I should do this outside and only handle the UI stuff in the extension in order to lighten the memory usage.

A good example I'm following is SwiftKey, which asks the user to grant full access in order to compute the predictions. Therefore, I believe it does this job outside the extension and send it back to it.

So my question is : is this possible ? If so, how ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by moving my predictions system into the container and made it communicating with its extension through NSUserDefaults and by Darwin notifications.

Remaining problem is the container's background state time limit.

Comment: How exactly did you run the container code from the extension in the background? I'm also  preparing some data in the extension, which needs to be executed by the code of the main app. But I don't know how to start the execution in the background of the main app.

Comment: @mixable I used Darwin notifications. It's the only way to do this and you'll need to ask the user to grant full access to your app. I still can't wake my container up when it's in background and inactive after 2 minutes tho...